# If - notlike - Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory, comparison

I want to add the value "ABC" to the AD-attribute called "myvariables" for an Organizational Unit - **but only if this value does not already exist.**

I've tried this:

```
$p = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $identity -Properties myvariables|Select-Object myvariables
If ($p.myvariables -notlike "*ABC*") {Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $identity -Add @{myvariables="ABC"}}
```

But that does not work. The value "ABC" for the AD-attribute will be set, even if it is already set.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Start debugging by printing `$p.myvariables` before entering the if branch. Also, consider printing just the `$p` variable.

Comment: I did that. It recognizes that $p already has the value "ABC" ($p={ABC})=> nevertheless it overwrites the value

Comment: `$MyVariables` is plural and that implies the variable holds a  _collection_. if that is correct ... then using `-Like` on a collection going to have what is likely to be unexpected results. _what is in the `$MyVariables` the variable when you try to use it? _exactly what is in it_?

Comment: If `$p` is the string `{ABC}`, it cannot contain property `.myvariables`. So, see what  printing `$p.myvariables` and `$p.gettype()` will return.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code in the question, and clarifications in the comments, it becomes clear that $p.myvariables is an **array** of strings.

In the `IF` statement you wrote `If ($p.myvariables -notlike "*ABC*")` that means - find me all elements of the array that are not like `"*ABC*"`. Consequently, the `IF` condition will be $true if the array contains any elements except "ABC". Thus, it produces the results you don't expect.

**Example**

```
PS C:\> $myvariables = "ZZZ","ABC","XXX"
PS C:\> $myvariables -like "*ABC*"      
ABC                                     
PS C:\> $myvariables -notlike "*ABC*"   
ZZZ                                     
XXX
```

What you probably want to use in your `IF` statement is `-in` or `-notIn`:

```
PS C:\> $myvariables = "ZZZ","ABC","XXX"
PS C:\> "ABC" -in $myvariables
True
PS C:\> "ABC" -notin $myvariables
False
```